# How to retrieve the value of a listener passed to a Stream?

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
Stream<int> get ints async* {
  yield 100;
}
  
Future<int> foo(int i) async {
  print(i);
  return 0;
}
  
void main() {
  final subscription = ints.listen(foo);

  // I thought something like this could work...
  subscription.asFuture().then((value) => print('value = $value')); 
}
```

How can I retrieve the value of `foo` function (i.e. `0`) from the `StreamSubscription` instance?

Comment: check `Stream.toList` method

Comment: @pskink I actually want to get the value of `foo` listener which is `0` in this example.

Comment: if you see `Stream.listen` official documentation you will see `void onData(T event)?,` which means that framework does not care about any value returned by a callback - in other words: whatever you return from there is ignored